# How to display particular department details from dept tables and then employee details in emp table and department wise employee count and total cnt

Tags: oracle, plsql

[click here to see the o/p image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwwkc.png)

Scott schema emp and dept table,write a plsql block or procedure
out put shoud come like

```
DEPTNO- 10   dname- Accounting

empno, ename, sal, comm,totalsal,

1,      a,     344, 5,     349

DEPTNO- 20   dname- reasearch

empno, ename, sal, comm, totalsal

2,      b,     334, 5 ,    339,

3,      cd ,    354,      354,

DEPTNO- 30   dname- sales

empno, ename, sal, comm,totalsal,

4,      bh,     334, 5,     339

5,     cu,     354 ,  null   354,

DEPTNO- 40   dname- sales
empno, ename, sal, comm,totalsal,

.

.

total no of employee in deptno 10  -2

total no of employee in deptno 20  -3

total no of employee in deptno 30  -4

total no of employee in deptno 40  -0


total employee 9
```

Answer (score 1):

That's two nested loops; one per departments, one per employees. Another loop to count employees per departments. Make it prettier, if you want.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_total_emps number := 0;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_d in (select deptno, dname from dept order by deptno) loop
  5      dbms_output.put_Line('Deptno: ' || cur_d.deptno ||' - '|| cur_d.dname);
  6      dbms_output.put_line('No   Ename    sal    comm totalsal');
  7      dbms_output.put_line('---- -------- ------ ---- --------');
  8      for cur_e in (select empno,
  9                           rpad(ename, 8, ' ') ename,
 10                           to_char(sal, '99990') sal,
 11                           to_char(comm, '9990') comm,
 12                           to_char(sal + nvl(comm, 0), '99999990') totalsal
 13                    from emp
 14                    where deptno = cur_d.deptno
 15                   ) loop
 16        dbms_output.put_line(cur_e.empno ||' - '|| cur_e.ename ||' - '||
 17                             cur_e.sal   ||' - '|| cur_e.comm  ||' - '||
 18                             cur_e.totalsal);
 19      end loop;
 20      dbms_output.put_line(chr(10));
 21    end loop;
 22
 23    for cur_r in (select deptno, count(*) cnt from emp
 24                  group by deptno order by deptno) loop
 25      dbms_output.put_line('Total employees in dept. ' || cur_r.deptno ||': '|| cur_r.cnt);
 26      l_total_emps := l_total_emps + cur_r.cnt;
 27    end loop;
 28    dbms_output.put_line('Total employees: ' || l_total_emps);
 29  end;
 30  /
```

---

```
Deptno: 10 - ACCOUNTING
No   Ename    sal    comm totalsal
---- -------- ------ ---- --------
7782 - CLARK    -   2450 -  -      2450
7839 - KING     -   5000 -  -      5000
7934 - MILLER   -   1300 -  -      1300


Deptno: 20 - RESEARCH
No   Ename    sal    comm totalsal
---- -------- ------ ---- --------
7369 - SMITH    -    800 -  -       800
7566 - JONES    -   2975 -  -      2975
7788 - SCOTT    -   3000 -  -      3000
7876 - ADAMS    -   1100 -  -      1100
7902 - FORD     -   3000 -  -      3000


Deptno: 30 - SALES
No   Ename    sal    comm totalsal
---- -------- ------ ---- --------
7499 - ALLEN    -   1600 -   300 -      1900
7521 - WARD     -   1250 -   500 -      1750
7654 - MARTIN   -   1250 -  1400 -      2650
7698 - BLAKE    -   2850 -    -1 -      2849
7844 - TURNER   -   1500 -     0 -      1500
7900 - JAMES    -    950 -    -1 -       949


Deptno: 40 - OPERATIONS
No   Ename    sal    comm totalsal
---- -------- ------ ---- --------


Total employees in dept. 10: 3
Total employees in dept. 20: 5
Total employees in dept. 30: 6
Total employees: 14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```